# DrawerLayout with LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, drawerlayout

Good afternoon, I'm putting DrawerLayout component in my app and I'm having the problem illustrated below. Does anyone know how to solve? Sorry for English mistakes ..

Image of problem: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1oxt6yr2vtf81qq/device-2014-01-14-162131.jpg

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/indicator"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/actionBottom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#e8e8e8"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnOrderBy"
            style="@style/btnPadrao"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClickOrderBy"
            android:text="Ordenação"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_controles" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutDrawer"
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMensagens"
        style="@style/btnPadrao"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:text="Enviar Mensagem"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_controles" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnChamadas"
        style="@style/btnPadrao"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Realizar Chamada"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_controles" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Does anyone know how to solve?

Thanks for help,
Gabriel Braga

Comment: What's the problem? Sorry, can't tell from the picture...

Comment: I also don't get the problem from the picture. seems just fine for me. btw, you can use an alternative navigation drawer: http://simonvt.github.io/android-menudrawer/